# Wordpress: как выбрать главную категорию для поста?

Tags: wordpress

Есть пост "Милые котята", он принадлежит к 4 категориям:

- Котята
- Котята→милые
- Няшности
- На главную

Wordpress выбирает для url поста категорию с наименьшим id, у меня это "на главную", но мне нужна возможность для каждого конкретного поста выбрать "главную" категорию самостоятельно, потому что категории могут добавляться/удаляться со временем, а название категории участвует в URL, где "на главную" вообще видеть не хочется.

Вопрос собственно в том какими средствами можно контролировать выбор главной категории и что будет происходить если "главная" категория будет удалена?

Comment: Полагаю что простейший путь лежит через custom fields, в наличии есть плагин Advanced Custom Fields, который уже используется для других целей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл плагин для этого дела, "Hikari Category Permalink" и более ранний "[sCategory Permalink](https://github.com/kpumuk/scategory-permalink/)", а также их форки. Плагины работают именно по озвученной в вопросе схеме, форки отличаются только поддержкой woocommerce и чистотой кода. Основной функционал — использование add_rewrite_tag